# "你睡他那层不就得了吗" what does it mean? “不就得了”

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?
I understand all the characters, but cannot understand the sentence i saw in a tv series. 不就得了， how to translate this?

Comment: it can be translated to 'why not ...'.

Comment: It's literality translated "wouldn't that OK?" It implies that "I" recommend you do that.

Answer (score 3):

The most important part is that the speaker is impatient now, and want to suggest something simple to stop the conversation.

- 不: isn't it xxx?
- 就：imediately become
- 得: achieve, solve
- 了: finish indicator
- XXX 不就得了 ：If XXX was done, isn't the problem solved?

(let me try another version) Isn't XXX good enough to solve the problem?

(Or simply) Why not just XXX

It would be exchangeable with 不如就XXX！

Example:

A: 我非常不想去这个聚会，里面有不想面对的人。I don't want to go to this party. There is someone I don't want to meet.

B: 不去不就得了。 Why not just not going there.

Or similarly

B: 不如就不去。

Answer (score 2):

不就得了 is an oral and informal phrase which usually used in giving someone some simple and clear recommendations(or answers/advices...etc).

e.g.

> A:這雨下太大了，該怎麼去買中餐？
>
> B:叫外送不就得了？ (or 自己煮不就得了？ )

> A:這中文作文題目好難啊！
>
> B:你先思考一下題目的意思，再用你的生活經驗回答不就得了？

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure what 不就得了 means without more context.

It seems to get translated as 'just' quite often.

你睡他那层不就得了吗？
you sleep (on) his floor (of the building) why not
Why don't you (just) sleep on his floor (of the building)? [Maybe it is higher and quieter???]

你去哪?穿上不就得了。
Where are you going? Just try them on. / Why not try them on?

乔治：你把她赶出去不就得了。
George: (You) Just kick her out. / Why don't you just kick her out?

那你把钱还给我不就得了！
Well, just give me my money back. / Well, why not just give me my money back.

许多人会说‘再买一个宠物不就得了嘛’。
A lot of people will say, "Just buy another pet." / "Why not (just) buy another pet?"

Answer (score 0):

**[KEY](https://cjkware.com/)**

> 不就得了
> bù jiùdéle
> (rhetorical question tagged onto the end of sentence, indicating "...will be good enough," often implying the speaker is dissatisfied or impatient)

**[Adsotrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsotrans#:%7E:text=With%20over%20195%2C000%20entries%2C%20Adso,by%20users%20through%20an%20online)**

> PHRASE
> and won't that be the end of it

---

<sup><sub>Treat yourself to some dictionaries - your language learning skills will thank you for it.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>You can buy KEY as a dictionary add-on in [Pleco](https://store.pleco.com/products.php), I'd highly recommend it for anyone looking to get into some more comprehensive C-E lexicons.</sub></sup>

> <sup><sub>KEY Chinese-English Dictionary - $19.99
>
> Up-to-date and very comprehensive Chinese-English dictionary with over 280,000 entries (but no examples); adapted from the PC software of the same name.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>I've never played with their PC software so I cannot comment on that.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>Adsotrans is also a free dictionary add-on in Pleco, if you're looking on saving some dosh.</sub></sup>